# How to make my image to keep getting smaller responsively?

Tags: css

When my browser size is under 950px, my main image stop getting smaller and start to hide behind the browser  window. I have tried to change the width, but than I'm starting to see my background-color. Why is that and how can I fix it?

This is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/pVpZRG)
And part of my code:

```
#image {
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ed1c24;
object-fit: cover;
```

}

By the way, I don't know if it's customary here or not (and if not, just tell me so) to ask two questions in one post, I don't why my media stop respond, and when I get to 830px, nothing changes. It worked like two minutes ago.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this on the #image:

```
height: auto;
```

And you are missing a bracket at the first media query (line 189), that's why the others don't work.

Also, top, bottom, left and right have no effect when position is set to relative.

EDIT: I played around with some other elements in your Codepen. This should be closer to what you want: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZEOdW?editors=1100
At least you can compare it to your version, might be helpful :)

Comment: When I change to height to 'auto', indeed to image keep getting smaller, but now, where the image before stooped getting smaller, the .headline-box looses his position from fixed-bottom to g after the image. Do you know how to fix it? And for the brackets... WOW I totally missed that one.  Thank very much for both!